# Crypto market update function in NodeJS not displaying "5 biggest losers" properly

Tags: node.js, arrays, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

Im using CoinCap API https://docs.coincap.io/ to grab current marketprices of the top 100 crypto currencies, then displaying the 5 coins that are down the most % (aka biggest losers). im making an array of 5 coins, iterating through each coin from the return from the api call, and comparing that coin to the 5 coins currently in the array.

if the coin is down more in the past 24h than the current coin in the array, replace it.

I was expecting the 5 biggest losers, instead i got 5 losers that I know are not the "biggest" losers (aka. there are other coins that are down more)

here is some of my code , the problem should be a simple logic issue that my brain is too worn down to notice, but let me know if i can provide any more info!

```
res.on("end", function () 
    {
      var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      var data = JSON.parse(body.toString());

      if (data && data.data) 
      {
        var assets = data.data;
        var losers = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) 
        {
          var asset = assets[i];

          if (losers.length < 5) 
          {
            losers.push(asset);
          } 
          else 
          {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
            {
              if (asset.changePercent24Hr < losers[j].changePercent24Hr) {
                losers[j] = asset;
                break; 
              }
            }
          }
        }

        console.log("Top Losers:\n")
        for (var i = 0; i < losers.length; i++) {
          console.log( losers[i].name + " Price: " + formatter.format(losers[i].priceUsd) + " 24h: " + Number.parseFloat(losers[i].changePercent24Hr).toFixed(2) + "%");
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        console.log("No data found.");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Imagine what happens if the current losers array is `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` and you are coming in with a new value of `5` ... You will lose your value `10` from the array, because you just replace it with `5` instead you have to insert `5` at the beginning, shift the other values `10, 20, 30, 40` towards the end of the array and finally remove the `50` because it's not in the top (or bottom) 5 anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

solution - i simply added every coin to the array and then sorted it in descending order and popped 5 from it. probably less efficient this way but itll do for now, thanks to @derpirscher for the help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
res.on("end", function () {
  var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  var data = JSON.parse(body.toString());

  if (data && data.data) {
    var assets = data.data;

    // Sort assets by changePercent24Hr in descending order
    assets.sort((a, b) => b.changePercent24Hr - a.changePercent24Hr);

    console.log("Top Losers:\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 && i < assets.length; i++) {
      var asset = assets[i];
      console.log(
        asset.name +
          " Price: " +
          formatter.format(asset.priceUsd) +
          " 24h: " +
          Number.parseFloat(asset.changePercent24Hr).toFixed(2) +
          "%"
      );
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No data found.");
  }
});
```

The assets are first sorted in descending order based on the `changePercent24Hr`. Then, you iterate through the sorted assets and print the top 5 biggest losers. Please correct me if I was wrong. Thank you.